# how to display a image in java application after downloading the image

Tags: java, image, swing

i want to display a image after downloading that image from a web-server

i have wrote the code for downloading the image. but i cant set it up to a label or any thing other than jframe (because i want to add more buttons and labels to the GUI).

here is the code to download the image from the webserver. now i want to set it to a label. please help me

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.personal.psu.edu/acr117/blogs/audrey/images/image-2.jpg");
image = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Comment: You asked the same question 3 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943680/how-to-display-a-image-in-java-application Please don't duplicate questions. If you can't find your questions back, please click anywhere your name appears as a link (e.g. in top bar) for your question history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Comment: this is when we writing a new label. but if we using a drag and drop label. how to do it.